# Modifying Proxy settings using android code with the connected wifi hotspot

Tags: java, android, proxy

I have created a hotspot from my windows7 machine and trying to write a code to connect my android phone to that hotspot.
I have been able to connect the phone.
Further I am trying to modify the proxy settings like IP and port for the connected hotspot using the code.
The phone is connecting to the hotspot but the code is unable to modify the proxy settings.

The code I have written is as follows:

**Main_activity.java**

> I am connecting wifi hotspot created in vb.net and then connecting phone to that hotspot

`  Package com.example.connect_avek;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.ProxyInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button startbtn,stopbtn;
    RelativeLayout background;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        stopbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbtn);


        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //start connection code
             WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
                wc.SSID = "\"" + "shashank" + "\"";  // Please note the quotes. String should contain SSID in quotes

                wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + "mummy@123" + "\"";

                wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);

                Log.d("connecting", wc.SSID + " " + wc.preSharedKey);

                wifi.addNetwork(wc);

                Log.d("after connecting", wc.SSID + " " + wc.preSharedKey);


                List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
                for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
                    if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + "shashank" + "\"")) {
                        wifi.disconnect();
                        wifi.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                        wifi.reconnect();
                        Log.d("re connecting", i.SSID + " " + wc.preSharedKey);
                        try {
                            Class proxyInfoClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyInfo");
                            Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
                            setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyInfoClass;
                            Class wifiConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
                            Method setHttpProxy = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy", setHttpProxyParams);
                            setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

                            //Method 1 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
                            Class ipConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration");
                            Field f = ipConfigClass.getField("proxySettings");
                            Class proxySettingsClass = f.getType();

                            //Method 2 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
                            //Note the $ between the class and ENUM
                            //Class proxySettingsClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration$ProxySettings");

                            Class[] setProxySettingsParams = new Class[1];
                            setProxySettingsParams[0] = proxySettingsClass;
                            Method setProxySettings = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setProxySettings", setProxySettingsParams);
                            setProxySettings.setAccessible(true);


                            ProxyInfo pi = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy("192.168.137.1", 7777);
                            //Android 5 supports a PAC file
                            //ENUM value is "PAC"
                            //ProxyInfo pacInfo = ProxyInfo.buildPacProxy(Uri.parse("http://localhost/pac"));

                            //pass the new object to setHttpProxy
                            Object[] params_SetHttpProxy = new Object[1];
                            params_SetHttpProxy[0] = pi;
                            setHttpProxy.invoke(wc, params_SetHttpProxy);

                            //pass the enum to setProxySettings
                            Object[] params_setProxySettings = new Object[1];
                            params_setProxySettings[0] = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) proxySettingsClass, "STATIC");
                            setProxySettings.invoke(wc, params_setProxySettings);

                            //save the settings
                            wifi.updateNetwork(wc);
                            wifi.disconnect();
                            wifi.reconnect();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.v("wifiProxy", e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                }
            }


        });
        stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //stop connection code
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
        });

            }
} `

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

**manifest.xml**
```

> I have added the wifi permissions for the internet state and activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.connect_avek" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you found any solution for this? I am also in the same issue.